# Why countBuffer(2, 3) omit every third value

Tags: rxjs

I don't understand why every third value is overlooked.

```
const source = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
const bufferThree = source.bufferCount(2, 3);
const subscribe = bufferThree.subscribe(val => console.log('Buffered Values:', val));
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whity/xa5dkfsj/2/)

If case of bufferCount(2, 1) each buffer will include also the previous value:

```
Buffered Values: (2) [0, 1]
Buffered Values: (2) [1, 2]
Buffered Values: (2) [2, 3]
```

I thought that startBufferEvery value always will be included into next output.

Regards

Comment: `startBufferEvery` will start a new buffer every `n`th item.

Comment: martin is correct. Is there some desired behavior you're trying to achieve with this particular usage?

Comment: Thanks guys. I'am just learning rxjs and wanna to understand it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bufferCount( X, Y)`
X is the size of the buffer
Y is the start of the next buffer

Therefor `bufferCount(2,3)` means that the first two values will get buffered, and the next buffer will start after the third value.
As a result the third value gets discarded

`bufferCount(2,1)` is the same, just that no value gets omited, but used twice.
The buffer is two values big, but after each value a new buffer gets started.
As a result you have two buffers running at the same time.

Comment: Thanks JanRecker. One more question.  So we can say, that 2 buffers can works 
at the same time, but the buffer that stopped emitting values ​​is cleared?

Comment: No, its "emited (means provided down the stream to the subscriber) and with that this specific buffer is not used anymore.  "bufferCount( X, Y ) creates all Y emits a new buffer, it gets filled with the values of X emits, then the buffer gets send down the stream to the subscriber.